# Memset and NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I am trying the wipe off sensitive data in iPhone app after done with it. Specially the NSStrings I am using to hold passwords etc. Can I use memset for this ?

Comment: Please show the code that you use to do `memset`.

Comment: No, unless you *really* know what you're doing and are *very* careful (and understand you're violating all sorts of Apple rules), using memset on an NSString would be virtually suicidal.  You *might* be able to achieve your desired functionality by using NSMutableStrings and setting them to garbage after use, but you have no guarantees that internally they're not buffer swapping.  Perhaps a safer/simpler approach would be to simply fill memory with garbage, though there would be no guarantees there either.

Comment: @HotLicks can you give some sort of code example that how will you fill memory with garbage. I am in need of same kind of help.

Comment: @rustylepord Did you manage to solve your problem? If yes would you mind sharing the answer here which can be helpful to others?

Comment: @SatishM If you are doing this throughout the app you need to be extra careful , this can introduce lot of crashes. Therefore I gave up the idea.